# How to avoid continuation of Tasks with TaskContinuationOptions

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I understand that `TaskContinuationOptions` allows or deny to continue the process of execution for chained Tasks, my below sample I'm not sure how to produce an error and consequently do not continue with last Task, could you please advice?

```cs
Task<string> T1= Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    return "Step 1.";
});

Task<string> T2= T1.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    return "Step 2.";
});

Task<string> T3= T2.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    return "Step 3";
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

Task<string> T4= T3.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    return "Step 4.";
});
```

Comment: Use async-await.

Comment: could you elaborate more your answer?

Comment: The `ContinueWith` method is [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Use it with care. Even better, don't use it at all.

Comment: @Vmax What would be the expected behaviour?

Comment: It's supposed when a previous task in chain fails... the next are going to be broken, do we agree? @Peter Csala

Comment: As it was stated by Nick you should place `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` at T4 to say *please run this operation only if the preceding (T3) operation's status is RanToCompletion otherwise do not run that*. So T4 won't be broken it simply won't run because its precondition / prerequisite is not met. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

Your test is incorrect: you use `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` when you create task `T3`, but since T2 always runs to completion, T3 gets executed, and so does T4.  You need to use `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` when you create T4.

`TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` means that the task you create by calling `ContinueWith` will run only if the ascedent task, i.e., the previous task, runs to completion.

Comment: Hello @Nick I did it but its not working, i throw a new exception and fails, but not really for the TaskContinuationOptions

Key question would be... how exactly a task cannot be completed... would be any kind of exception or anything else?